# How to remove Favicon in Springboot application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to remove favicon in my spring boot application. I tried to include below property in application.properties file. but still not able to achieve it.

```
spring​.​mvc​.​favicon​.​enabled
```

I followed the below link also but it is not working. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-favicon

Comment: do you tried point 4 of the link?

Comment: What's your Spring Boot version?

Comment: Yes #Patrick I tried point 4 also.

Comment: #lakatos-gyula I am using <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>